How to write a query re-format results so one column becomes row headers with distinct results
Newbie to MySQL 8. In my exercise I have three tables. Table one with unique foods (sort of branded names), table two with nutrients and table three is a junction table to join both with amounts of nutrients for each food. I need help to write two takes on (pivot?) queries to convert:

Column with food_name into a table headers row. Another column with nutrients to be a left side column.
Column with nutrients into a table headers row and the column with food_name to be on the left side. And, because nutrients are common to foods, grouping by nutrients is required

Values with amounts are either displayed for each combination of food_name/nutrient_name or display dash "-" if it is missing. The number of foods in the table is dynamic but to display it on a screen I want to limit to 15. So, having 150 food items in food table would have to create 10 tables as on the sample below.
The solution below (link) as suggested to me by site admins with using case-statement would work for some constant values like months, provinces or some limited lookup items but, in this cast this will not work because the data in both 'food' and 'nutrient' tables is dynamic and can reach hundreds of food items and not as many but, also substantial number of nutrients, minerals etc.
How can I return pivot table output in MySQL?
Table DDL below:
CREATE TABLE food (
 food_id int,
 description text  
);
CREATE TABLE food_nutrient (
 food_id int,
 nutrient_id int,
 amount double
);
CREATE TABLE nutrient (
 nutrient_id int DEFAULT NULL,
 name text
);    
insert into food(food_id, description)
values
  (1, 'cookies'),
  (2, 'coffee'),
  (3, 'tea');

insert into nutrient(nutrient_id, name)
values
 (10, 'vitamin b'),
 (11, 'vitamin c'),
 (12, 'water'),
 (15, 'sugar');
 (22, 'fatty acid'),
 (33, 'sodium');        

 insert into food_nutrient(food_id, nutrient_id, amount)
 values
  (1, 11, 1),
  (1, 12, 2),   
  (1, 33, 3),   
  (2, 12, 10),
  (2, 33, 2),
  (3, 12, 15),
  (3, 15, 8);
  select description, name, amount
   from food f
   join food_nutrient fn on fn.food_id = f.food_id
   join nutrient n on n.nutrient_id = fn.nutrient_id

The result of the query below:
Description |   Name        |   Amount
---------------------------------------
cookies     |   vitamin c   |   1
cookies     |   water       |   2
cookies     |   sodium      |   3
coffee      |   water       |   10
coffee      |   sodium      |   2
tea         |   water       |   15
tea         |   sugar       |   8

I need this to look like this:
Nutrients   |   cookies     |   coffee      |   tea
----------------------------------------------------
vitamin c   |   1           |   -           |   -
vitamin b   |   -           |   -           |   -
fatty acid  |   -           |   -           |   -
sodium      |   3           |   2           |   -
water       |   2           |   10          |   15
sugar       |   -           |   -           |   8

Solved this one with the following query, perhaps someone will find it useful
set @sql = (
select group_concat(distinct 
    concat("sum(ifnull(case when food_name='", food_name, "' 
                        then fn.amount end
                        ,0)) as ", food_name, ""
    )) 
from food1 f
join food_nutrient1 fn on fn.food_id = f.food_id
join nutrient1 n on n.nutrient_id = fn.nutrient_id    
);

set @sql = concat(
      "select nutrient_name, ", 
      @sql, 
      " from nutrient1 n 
      join food_nutrient1 fn on fn.nutrient_id = n.nutrient_id 
      join food1 f on f.food_id = fn.food_id 
      group by nutrient_name"
);
prepare stat from @sql;
execute stat;


That's converting rows to column, not columns to row.

Should probably be more clear, to make Description as distinct row headers
